# How to get/submit comments of any youtube video using "google-api-objectivec-client"

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, xcode5

I am using

[google-api-objectivec-client] (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/)

I want to get the comments of any youtube video. if any one have tried it please guide me how can i do it.

This is my code to get most popular videos

```
- (void)getMostPopularOnCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion withCurrentUserChannel:(GTLYouTubeChannel*)currentUserChannel{

    mostPopularFlag = YES;
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.revealController.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";

    GTLQueryYouTube *videoQuery = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"id, snippet, contentDetails, statistics" Chart:@"mostPopular"];
    videoQuery.maxResults = 50;

    //    if(nextPageToken){
    //        videoQuery.pageToken = nextPageToken;
    //    }

    [_menu.youtubeService executeQuery:videoQuery
                     completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *object, NSError *error) {
                         _mostPopularVideos = [object.items mutableCopy];
                         _mostPopularVideosOriginal = [object.items mutableCopy];
                         [_filterSegmentO setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
                         [_mainTableView setAccessibilityHint:@"0"];
                         [hud hide:YES];
                         hud=nil;
                         [_mainTableView setTag:0];
                         [_mainTableView reloadData];
                         for (int i = 0; i < object.items.count; i++) {
                             GTLYouTubeVideo *video = object.items[i];
                             [self getChannelImage:video.snippet.channelId];
                         }

                        if (completion){
                             completion();
                         }
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments read/write is not available on Data API v3 yet (which is objc-client is based of). But you can [read through the old API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments).